# os/exec: не могу запустить несколько команд

Tags: windows, golang, cmd, ос

Есть код который по идее должен работать нормально но это не так:

```golang
if c, err := exec.Command("cmd","/c","mkdir", "name", "cd", "name", "mkdir", "messages").CombinedOutput(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
} else {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", c)
}
```

Ошибка:

```
2019/10/10 15:04:44 exit status 1
```

Если зайти и посмотреть что же сделала наша программа увидим несколько новых папок:

1. `cd`
2. `messages`
3. `mkdir`
4. `name`

В чем конкретно проблема знать не знаю, кажется эта команда способна отработать только один запрос, или я что-то не так написал.

Comment: как это исправить, вы же понимаете что я хочу сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас тут три команды: `mkdir name`,
`cd name`, и `mkdir messages`.  И комбинируются
они не так.  В батнике это было бы:

```bat
set cc="mkdir .\a && cd .\a && mkdir .\b"
cmd /c %cc%
```

Обратите внимание на оператор `&&`.

Во-вторых, для того, что вы хотите сделать, есть вполне адекватные
методы стандартной библиотеки:

```golang
// Unix permissions:
//   u: user  g: group
//   o: others
//   r: read  w: write   u   g   o
//   x: execute          rwx rwx rwx
var perm os.FileMode = 0b111_000_000
err = os.MkdirAll(`.\name\messages`, perm)
// Check err.
```

(Бинарные литералы — новое в *Go* 1.13.)

Версия для *Windows* может ещё чем-то отличаться, это уже ваша
«домашняя работа».  Документация:

- *Wikipedia*: [*Batch file*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)
- *The Go Programming Langauge: os*: [`os.MkdirAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/os#MkdirAll)